# Nutritional counselling -> Nutritional counsellor?

Tags: word-request

The person who provides nutritional counselling is

> a nutritional counsellor/consultant/specialist

or something else?

Comment: Any of those terms would be acceptable, but, as Maulik's answer shows, English also has single-word terms for the people who work in this field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call them...

> [a dietician](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/DIETITIAN) - A specialist in the study of nutrition

Another word is:

> [a nutritionist](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/NUTRITIONIST)

---

The confusion is obvious to many as a dietician **not necessarily** advises you *only* on *how to lose weight.*

Comment: You bring up an excellent point. Sometimes we invent new terms because an older one carries a connotation we don't want. For example, if I'm a dietician, and I want to start working with high-level athletes, I might decide "nutritional expert" would look better on my business card than "dietician" – even though the latter would mean the same thing.